# CakePHP: allowing login with user name or email

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm implementing a logic where you can use either your username or email address to log in in CakePHP. I'm following an example in a book called CakePHP 1.3: Application Development Cookbook (Chapter 1: Allowing logins with username or email). The book explains that when the Auth component cannot log the user in with the provided info, it goes back to the login() action and can look for additional info that might log the user in with the logic within the login() action.

The code/logic is working. However, when I login with my email address, it still displays the loginError message, which says "Invalid account specified." Below that it says "Welcome," which is a message I display when a login is successfull.

These are what I'd like to know:

1. The book doesn't indicate whether or not this is normal, but I'd like to learn how to omit this error message, since it doesn't make sense. Where is THIS LINE (in comment) taking the user? The error message displays after that line.
2. .. and possibly display with "you logged logged in with email." This is of secondary importance.

Below are what I think relevant code. Please let me know if you need more.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => 'controller',
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'admin' => false,
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ),
        'loginError' => 'Invalid account specified',
        'authError' => 'You don\'t have the right permission'
    ),
    'Session'
);
}


class UsersController extends AppController {
public function login() {
    if (
        !empty($this->data) &&
        !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['username']) &&
        !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['password'])
    ) {
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.email' => $this->Auth->data['User']['username'],
                'User.password' => $this->Auth->data['User']['password']
            ),
            'recursive' => -1
        ));

        if (!empty($user) && $this->Auth->login($user)) {   // $this->Auth->login() true if logs in
            if ($this->Auth->autoRedirect) {    // I think autoRedirect is TRUE by default

                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); // <<THIS LINE>>
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash($this->Auth->loginError, $this->Auth->flashElement, array(), 'auth');
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (!empty($user) && $this->Auth->login($user)) {
        $this->Session->delete('Message.auth');
    }
```

You don't need to setFlash for authError if you flash('auth') in login view (as in the cookbook) and you don't need to call redirect.

Comment: are you saying that the last else-statement is unnecessary (setFlash(...))? Could you explain your answer a little more about flash('auth') in the login view? BTW, the redirect seems to be necessary if I want to direct the user to a page other than the login page. Without it, I get logged on, but I'm still on the login page (unable to tell I logged successfully without trying to navigate to other restricted pages).

Comment: See here http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication It auto-redirects based on the setting in Auth (otherwise, why do you think you can leave the login() empty in the default setup?)

Answer (score 0):

Its the same code explained in http://www.packtpub.com/cakephp-1-3-application-development-cookbook/book CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook
,
I think it would be more effective like this

```
if(!empty($user) && $this->Auth->login($user)){
                if($this->Auth->autoRedirect){
                    $this->Session->delete('Message.auth'); // kills login failed message after successful login
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash($this->Auth->loginError, $this->Auth->flashElement, array(), 'auth');
                }
            }
```

this way login failed error message after successful login will be omitted and redirection will remain intact.